# Retrieving rows from self join in php

Tags: php, sql

I used self join for my table but I am not able to retrieve the table rows

```
$SQL1 = "SELECT e1.userid, e2.userid
FROM userfield AS e1, userfield AS e2
WHERE e1.field5 = e2.field5 and e1.field5!=' ' and e2.field5!=' ' and e1.userid!=e2.userid";

$result2 = mysql_query($SQL1);

while ($db_field2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    print $dbfield2[userid];  
}
```

when I am executing this code its just shows the blank page .And When i fire this query in msql database it returns two userids

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: 1. avoid using mysql_* for your php scripts, there are no longer mantained, use PDO or mysqli instead.
2. Provide more information of what's your expected output

Comment: What is the default join used in the `FROM userfield AS e1, userfield AS e2` clause? Does this do a JOIN on the 2 primary keys of the tables? i.e., `FROM userfield AS e1 JOIN userfield AS e2 ON e1.userid = e2.userid`

Comment: problem solved instead of fetch_assoc i use mysql_fetch_array and it works

Comment: thanx all for replying ..good luck

Comment: Do _not_ use `[userid]`, use `['userid']`, these strings need to be quited (while we are at it, enable full error_reporting & display_errors while you're developing, it would have told you that).

Answer (score 0):

```
$SQL1 = "SELECT e1.userid, e2.userid
    FROM userfield AS e1, userfield AS e2
    WHERE e1.field5 = e2.field5 and e1.field5!=' ' and e1.userid!=e2.userid";

$result2 = mysql_query($SQL1);

while ($db_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    print $db_row['e1.userid'];  
}
```

P.S. You don't need `and e2.field5!=' '` in `WHERE` clause because `e2.field5` must be equal to `e1.field5` and `e1.field5!=' '`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give them aliases like this:

```
$SQL1 = "SELECT e1.userid AS userid1, e2.userid AS userid2
         FROM userfield AS e1, userfield AS e2
         WHERE e1.field5 = e2.field5 and e1.field5!=' ' and e1.userid!=e2.userid";

$result2 = mysql_query($SQL1);

while ($db_field2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    print $dbfield2['userid1'];  
}
```

And please consider switching to PDO oder mysqli. All mysql_* functions are officially marked as deprecated.